# Why does this tuple have 2 elements?

Tags: functional-programming, ocaml

**let p = let x = 1 in x + 1, let y = 2 in y + 1, 4**

Since `comma ,` have the lowest precedence, I would image `p` has `3` elements: `(2, 3, 4)`.

But in fact, `p` has only `2` elements: `(2, (3, 4))`

**Why?**

Why the last `,` belongs to `let y` expression, but not outside of it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would expect `let...in...` to have the following syntax

> **let** *binding* =  *expression* **in** *expression*

and the block goes as far to the right as possible.

In your example, the OCaml parser expects

```
let y = 2 in y + 1, 4
```

to be an expression and parses it as `(3, 4)` successfully.

An equivalent of your example with explicit brackets is

```
let p = (let x = 1 in x + 1, (let y = 2 in y + 1, 4))
```

If you would like to return final result `(2, 3, 4)`, you should put a bracket to stop `let...in...` block in the appropriate place:

```
let p = let x = 1 in x + 1, (let y = 2 in y + 1), 4
```

Answer (score 0):

Try writing out on multiple lines, with indentation to show the relationship:

```
let p = 
    let x = 1 in x + 1, 
        let y = 2 in y + 1, 4
```

So you can see how one let "belongs" to another.

(2, (3,4)) is exactly what I'd expect.

Comment: thanks, but I don't think you have explained the root. I mean the deep inside reason

Comment: Does `let y = 2 in y + 1, 4` belong to `let x` expression?

Comment: Yes it does, although I may phrase it a bit differently.  But that is the deep inside reason, and the reason I wrote it out with indentation was to allow the structure to reveal that reason.  I added a bit more to my answer, to hopefully make it more useful.